# Допустимо ли "во рифму"?

Tags: орфография, лексика

Конечно, "в рифму" привычно, а "во рифму" режет ухо. Но допустимо ли так писать?

Comment: А что за контекст? Откуда вообще появилась эта идея писать "во рифму"?
Если вы нагружаете какй-то патетикой свою строку, то может оно и допустимо. 
Но уж очень странно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иначе никак нельзя - не позволительно по правилам, режет слух, ломает язык. Это правило хорошо объясняет  "СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ" Розенталя, §199.  Выбор предлога

> 9      В условиях контекста возможны дублеты типа в введении – во введении. Добавление гласного о к предлогу, состоящему из одного согласного звука или оканчивающемуся на согласный, наблюдается в ряде случаев:
>
> 1. перед односложным словом, начинающимся со стечения согласных, с беглым гласным в корне, например: во сне (ср.: в сновидениях), во рту (ср.: в ртутных испарениях), во льну (ср.: в льнотеребилках), ко мне (ср.: к мнимой величине);
> 2. часто после предлогов в и с, если с этих же согласных начинается последующее стечение согласных, например: во власти, во внушении, со слезами, со словами, со страху;
> 3. в отдельных фразеологических выражениях, например: во сто крат, изо всех сил, во главе войск, как кур во щи;
> 4. в текстах, имеющих оттенок торжественности, например: Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины... (Тургенев);
> 5. в сочетаниях официального стиля, например: во избежание, во исполнение, во имя (перед начальным гласным слова).

Comment: Спасибо. То есть есть конкретные правила, на интуицию и вкус здесь нельзя полагаться.

Answer (score 5):

Вспоминается сразу "во поле березка стояла". Но там удлинение предлога происходит в поэтической строке для создания напевного ритмического рисунка. Или "Во глубине сибирских руд храните гордое терпенье" - еще и для создания торжественной интонации. Конечно, если у Вас стилизация какая-то, т.е. употребление "во" обусловлено стилистическими причинами, тогда да. А в обычной речи правильно будет - "в рифму".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Конечно же "правильно" будет так, как все привыкли. Но что, если я буду использовать второй вариант (неважно почему), будет ли корректным замечание, что я допустил ошибку, и писать надо только "в рифму" и никак иначе?

Comment: Не будет, если употребляется с особой смысловой нагрузкой. Лapf уже объяснила выше про "поэтическую строку". Но будет смешно выглядеть "во рифму" в обычной речи, в бытовой ситуации, в разговоре, например, в (книжном) магазине. Оно вам надо — быть смешным?

Comment: >Но что, если я буду использовать второй вариант (неважно почему),  
То-то и оно, что важно. если у вас стих в размер не попадает, то это ошибка. А если вы сознательно пародируете речь Имерека Пупкина, то, может, оно так и надо.